# Spree Checkout api put method not working

Tags: spree

We are using spree version 2.0
We are implementing spree api. We keep spree as backend and trying to replicate the store. But spree checkout api is not working for us. When we create checkout by using "put" method it keeps the "state of order as cart" it doesn't change to "address state".

We tried making a PUT request to checkouts#next

```
  RestClient.put "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/checkouts/R87989987/next",{'token' => "xyz"}
```

But it failed with..

```
RestClient::UnprocessableEntity - 422 Unprocessable Entity:
```

Also, the API docs (http://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/checkouts.html) don't mention any #next action.

Can you point us to the correct direction?

Comment: Can you paste the response data? The JSON response usually says something. 422 usually means something didn't validate. The token should be a spree user api token. Go to the spree directory with cd `bundle show spree` and open the checkouts controller in api folder.